# Spark: How to read & write temporary files?

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming

I need to write a Spark app that uses temporary files.

I need to download many many large files, read them with some legacy code, do some processing, delete the file, and write the results to a database.

The files are on S3 and take a long time to download.  However, I can do many at once, so I want to download a large number in parallel.  The legacy code reads from the file system.

I think I can not avoid creating temporary files.  What are the rules about Spark code reading and writing local files?

This must be a common issue, but I haven't found any threads or docs that talk about it.  Can someone give me a pointer?

Many thanks
P

Comment: What are you trying to do with Spark here? use it as a parallel download utility from S3?

Comment: Yes, parallel download is the first step in my application.

Comment: Well, this is hardly the use case for Spark. I suppose that if you NFS mount a directory all spark instances would be able to write to it but I haven't tried it

Comment: Could you post the solution you used?